# Call vim command from shell, and suppress output while it operates

Tags: command-line, plugin-system, ex-mode, invocation

I'm setting up a vim environment install script. I'm using vim-plug for plugin management.
What I'd like to do is, from the install.sh, run vim and call PlugInstall to
 trigger plugin download and install.
The plugin file is set up to also set plugin-specific settings, so creates errors
relating to undefined variables when the plugins aren't installed (i.e., the
first time it starts up.) This requires user input of enter to bypass.

Ideally, the process would display the PlugInstall window and require no user 
input, without showing plugin error messages.
Second-best would be this, but the
error messages are still seen (still without requiring input).
3rd best would be to have no output, but quietly wait until the plugins are, in
fact, installed.

These are the commands I've tried so far, with their results.

Command runs with no error, but also doesn't actually do anything:

```
echo "PlugInstall" | vim -es
echo "PlugInstall|qa!" | vim -E
```

Plugin errors, enter ex then get stuck (treats arg as filename):

```
vim -ecs PlugInstall\|qa!
vim -ec silent PlugInstall\|qa!
vim -ec silent exec PlugInstall\|qa!
```

"Error reading input". Still get plugin errors:

```
echo ":PlugInstall" | vim
```

Plugin errors requiring enter to continue, then works as desired:

```
vim -c PlugInstall\|qa!
vim +PlugInstall! +qa!
```

Edit: Further experimentation managed to get a chimera working. This satisfies second-best outcome. However, it ruins the shell session: input doesn't show up, and the prompt is seriously misaligned.

```
printf "\n" | vim -c PlugInstall\|qa!
```

Edit: `vim -E +PlugInstall +qall` (mentioned in comments below) satisfies criteria 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I successfully used this command in a non-interactive way, but you have to specify the file containing the `Plug` calls:

```
vim -E -s -u "$HOME/.vimrc" +PlugInstall +qall
```

You might want to read more on how silent mode works with `:help -s-ex`, and maybe add the verbose argument (`-V`) for debugging.

Comment: It might be my terminal (WSL), but that not only didn't install the plugins, but ruined the shell session same as my final attempts.

Comment: What did finally work (Thank you!) was `vim -E +PlugInstall +qall`. (My vimrc was installed by that point, so I didn't need to specify it. It loaded the plug calls and their settings, which was why I was trying to get around the errors when they were missing.)
Still a minor problem with the terminal subsequently, in that the cursor went missing. But otherwise works.

Comment: For whatever reason, adding the `-s` flag stops it from actually installing the plugins.

Comment: Also for completeness, `vim -E +PlugInstall +qall` still showed the errors. It just didn't require input to bypass them. Fulfilled second-best outcome, with a usable terminal afterwards (albeit still not fully usable).

Comment: Fixed the cursor error by calling `printf "\033[?25h"` after the vim command. Calling reset also worked.

Comment: At the end of `:h silent-mode` you can read that `Initializations are skipped (except the ones given with the "-u" argument)`: adding `-s` has no effect without an explicit vimrc. Silent mode may also prevent the terminal issues.