# How do I perform a sanity check on my .vimrc from the shell programmatically?

Tags: vimrc

The other day I was using one of my non-interactive scripts to set up my dot files for my home directory, including my .vimrc file. This is what I had the script put into my .vimrc file:

```
. /etc/external/config.conf
```

This was before I knew vim can interpret 'source' but not '.' when sourcing external configuration. I thought my script worked well and then I got this error later when opening up vim:

```
search hit BOTTOM, continuing at TOPError detected while processing 
/home/demo/.vimrc:
line    1:
E486: Pattern not found: etc
```

It would have been really nice if I could have run some sort of sanity check on my .vimrc *in my script* so that I could have found out about my misconfigured settings sooner rather than later. How can I run a sanity check on my .vimrc configuration *from the shell programmatically, without user interaction*?

Comment: I think most people just try sourcing it (`:so %` if you're currently in the buffer or `:so %MYVIMRC` if you're not) or simply restart Vim.

Comment: @Rich I should have been more clear with my question. I need to be able to run the sanity check **from the shell**. I have a script that needs to run non-interactively, and in that script I am setting up my dot files in my home directory. If I have to open vim to check my .vimrc syntax, then my script would require user interaction (which I do not want).

Comment: Ohhh. I missed (or didn't grok) the words "in a script" in your original question. It makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be preferable to install an external tool, configurable depending on your needs: it may even have warnings you didn't know about.
I recommend [vint](https://github.com/Kuniwak/vint), which I use with [ale](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) for live linting.

---

But if you go down this path you need the command to fail (exit code != 0). You can achieve this with an intermediary file (instead of an inline command for readability), i.e. `test.vim`:

```
try
  source $HOME/.vimrc
  quit
catch
  cquit
endtry
```

The pattern (see `:h :catch`) should not only contain "Error detected while processing", or you would miss some messages.

Then you have to to verify if `vim -u test.vim` fails, for example in bash:

```bash
vim -N -u test.vim; [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Invalid .vimrc"
```

In my case I needed `-N` to avoid errors as I don't explicitly `set nocompatible` in my configuration.

Also, check [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15564/12003) about silent mode and running Vim non-interactively.

Answer (score 3):

```
vim -q fakefile >/dev/null 2>/tmp/checkforerrors; grep -q -F 'Error detected while processing ' /tmp/checkforerrors && echo '.vimrc syntax is bad' || echo '.vimrc syntax is good!!'; rm /tmp/checkforerrors
```

I would love to hear from some vi/vim experts about whether this command is safe and effective. Very ugly and hackish, but it seems to work well as a way to run a sanity check on my .vimrc file.

Comment: You can use the `-q` switch with `grep` instead of redirecting stdout and stderr to /dev/null. Ex: `grep -qF 'Error detected while processing ' && ...`